# Use `last` command to show non-interactive sessions

Tags: embedded, last

We use the command `last` to show if other users connected to an embedded system. For interactive ssh-sessions this works fine.

But we use MATLAB GPU coder which provides build code to embedded system. This Connections seems to happens as a non interactive Session (We also needed to provide the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to non interactive sessions).

Is it possible to get something similar as `last` but for non-interactive sessions? Since for the non-interactive sessions also authentications is necessary.

Comment: You may be looking for `w`. I am not completly sure which kind of sessions you want and which should be filtered.

Comment: THis only shows active connection right?

Comment: I am not sure. `w`, `who` and `last` are all similar and still different. That's why I only posted a comment and no answer.